# Como faço para obter a hora do Servidor ou a hora corrente do dia e mudar no sistema, via código?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Preciso atualizar um sistema O.S com a hora de outro micro, caso esse outro micro seria um servidor. Gostaria de fazer isso via código.

Outro método que também ajudaria seria pegar a hora certa do dia e comparar com o a do Computador que estará executando o programa.

Comment: Você precisa mesmo pegar alterar a hora do OS? Talvez seja melhor você sempre usar a data e hora do banco de dados, a do OS você pode não ter permissão para alterar, e se for uma rede corporativa o Windows pode já estar configurado para sincronizar a hora com o servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codigo em VB.NET Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c/12150289#12150289

```
 Public Shared Function GetNetworkTime() As DateTime
        'Servidor nacional para melhor latência
        Const ntpServer As String = "a.ntp.br"

        ' Tamanho da mensagem NTP - 16 bytes (RFC 2030)
        Dim ntpData = New Byte(47) {}

        'Indicador de Leap (ver RFC), Versão e Modo
        ntpData(0) = &H1B
        'LI = 0 (sem warnings), VN = 3 (IPv4 apenas), Mode = 3 (modo cliente)
        Dim addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList

        '123 é a porta padrão do NTP
        Dim ipEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(addresses(0), 123)
        'NTP usa UDP
        Dim socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)

        socket.Connect(ipEndPoint)

        'Caso NTP esteja bloqueado, ao menos nao trava o app
        socket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000

        socket.Send(ntpData)
        socket.Receive(ntpData)
        socket.Close()

        'Offset para chegar no campo "Transmit Timestamp" (que é
        'o do momento da saída do servidor, em formato 64-bit timestamp
        Const serverReplyTime As Byte = 40

        'Pegando os segundos
        Dim intPart As ULong = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ntpData, serverReplyTime)

        'e a fração de segundos
        Dim fractPart As ULong = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ntpData, serverReplyTime + 4)

        'Passando de big-endian pra little-endian
        intPart = SwapEndianness(intPart)
        fractPart = SwapEndianness(fractPart)

        Dim milliseconds = (intPart * 1000) + ((fractPart * 1000) / &H100000000L)

        'Tempo em **UTC**
        Dim networkDateTime = (New DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).AddMilliseconds(CLng(milliseconds))

        Return networkDateTime.ToLocalTime()
    End Function

    ' stackoverflow.com/a/3294698/162671
    Private Shared Function SwapEndianness(x As ULong) As UInteger
        Return CUInt(((x And &HFF) << 24) + ((x And &HFF00) << 8) + ((x And &HFF0000) >> 8) + ((x And &HFF000000UI) >> 24))
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    //necessário privilégio administrador
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetSystemTime", SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static bool Win32SetSystemTime(ref SystemTime sysTime);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSystemTime", SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static void Win32GetSystemTime(ref SystemTime sysTime);

    public struct SystemTime
    {
        public ushort Year;
        public ushort Month;
        public ushort DayOfWeek;
        public ushort Day;
        public ushort Hour;
        public ushort Minute;
        public ushort Second;
        public ushort Millisecond;
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        //servidor intranet "user-PC" (local)
        //a.ntp.br (internet) 
        //var localDateTime = PegarDtHoraRedeLocal("user-PC");
        var horaAtual = PegarDtHoraAtualizada("a.ntp.br");

        //AJUSTA HORA BASEADO NO FUSO HORARIO DO COMPUTADOR LOCAL
        SetTime(horaAtual.ToUniversalTime());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static DateTime PegarDtHoraAtualizada(string ntpServer)
    {
        var ntpData = new byte[48];
        ntpData[0] = 0x1B; //LeapIndicator = 0 (no warning), VersionNum = 3 (IPv4 only), Mode = 3 (Client Mode)

        //somente IPV4
        var addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList.First(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

        var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(addresses, 123);
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        socket.ReceiveTimeout = 5000; //5 segundos timeout
        socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
        socket.Send(ntpData);
        socket.Receive(ntpData);
        socket.Close();

        ulong intPart = (ulong)ntpData[40] << 24 | (ulong)ntpData[41] << 16 | (ulong)ntpData[42] << 8 | ntpData[43];
        ulong fractPart = (ulong)ntpData[44] << 24 | (ulong)ntpData[45] << 16 | (ulong)ntpData[46] << 8 | ntpData[47];

        var milliseconds = (intPart * 1000) + ((fractPart * 1000) / 0x100000000L);
        var networkDateTime = (new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)).AddMilliseconds((long) milliseconds).ToLocalTime();

        //ajustando para hora brasil teste ajuste independente do fuso horario
        //networkDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(networkDateTime.ToString(), "dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
        return networkDateTime;
    }

    private static void SetTime(DateTime dataHoraAtualizada)
    {
        // Prepare native method with the defined structure.
        var st = new SystemTime
        {
            Year = (ushort) (dataHoraAtualizada.Year),
            Month = (ushort) (dataHoraAtualizada.Month),
            Hour = (ushort) (dataHoraAtualizada.Hour),
            Day = (ushort) (dataHoraAtualizada.Day),
            Minute = (ushort) (dataHoraAtualizada.Minute),
            Second = (ushort) (dataHoraAtualizada.Second)
        };

        // Set the system date time.
        var resp = Win32SetSystemTime(ref st);
        Debug.Print(resp.ToString());
    }
}
```

> Preciso atualizar um sistema O.S com a hora de outro micro, caso esse
>   outro micro seria um servidor. Gostaria de fazer isso via código.

```
var localDateTime = PegarDtHoraRedeLocal("user-PC"); //user-PC: nome servidor sua rede local
//AJUSTA HORA BASEADO NO FUSO HORARIO DO COMPUTADOR LOCAL
SetTime(horaAtual.ToUniversalTime());
```

**OBS:**

1. O serviço Horário do Windows (W32Time) funciona como servidor responsável por prover a hora, portanto, o mesmo deve está iniciado;
2. Testei localmente computador com WINXP SP3 e WIN7 (Professional). XPSP3 não precisa de configuração adicional;
3. Para configurar WIN7 (como servidor NTP - Network Time Protocol) siga os passos abaixo:
   3.1 Pare o serviço (W32Time - Horário do Windows), pode ser pelo gerenciador de serviços ou pelo <kbd>prompt de comando</kbd><kbd>net stop w32time</kbd>
   3.2 Abra o registro do windows <kbd>regedit.exe</kbd>
   3.3 Navegue até a chave <kbd>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config\AnnounceFlags</kbd>  altere o valor de <kbd>10</kbd> para <kbd>5</kbd>
   3.4 Navegue até a chave <kbd>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpServer</kbd> 
   altere o valor para <kbd>1</kbd>
   3.5 Inicie o serviço (W32Time - Horário do Windows) <kbd>net start w32time</kbd>
   3.6 Para verificar se o servidor NTP está configurado corretamente, digite no <kbd>prompt de comando</kbd> <kbd>w32tm /query /configuration</kbd> e veja se aparece imagem abaixo está configurado
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Outro método que também ajudaria seria pegar a hora certa do dia e
>   comparar com o a do Computador que estará executando o programa.

Aqui você pega a hora certa do dia e pode comparar com a do seu servidor @felipe-walleg

```
var horaAtual = PegarDtHoraAtualizada("a.ntp.br"); //Hora atualizada pela internet    
//AJUSTA HORA BASEADO NO FUSO HORARIO DO COMPUTADOR LOCAL
SetTime(horaAtual.ToUniversalTime());
```

Fontes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172517(v=vs.90).aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ffb1df0b-7c6e-4b2d-8fdf-b4ca0c014266/configuring-windows-7-as-an-ntp-server?forum=winserverPN